# Java Threads (multithreading)

Tags: java, multithreading

How can I give input to threads in java

eg:

```
class BTT extends Threads
{
  int ag1;
  int ag2;

  void build(int k)
  {
     void build(k+1);
  }
}
```

I want to set the values of ag1 and k in build different in different threads. How can i do that?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit?  Also, please format the code so that it becomes easy to understand.

Comment: true I find it good system to appeal to the ego of devloppers to encourage them to have rewards when they answer ^^, but I don't think it should prevent from helping out.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66773/should-mods-delete-work-on-that-accept-rate-comments

Comment: @user440336 - it is not about prevention.  It is about people deciding for themselves how helpful they want to be to someone who is breaching etiquette.

Answer (score 1):

you treat your thread class as a simple POJO only (Java object) which can multiple values, i don't think that there should be such a big problem.

you can use something like the code below.

```
public class P1 extends Thread {

    private int age;

    public P1(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(this.age);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        P1 p1 = new P1(1);
        p1.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check program http://pastebin.com/wdsAxEQ6. The value of count is 1705 if I am not use threads but if i use thread the value of the count is > 1705. Is there away where i can make int count shared by two threads? I am doing anything wrong in the program?

Answer (score 0):

well when you create your thread you can do things like

```
MyThread mt = new MyThread(agr1, arg2);

mt.setValue(k);
```

but Java Threads usually uses Runnables
http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-threads-tutorial

in that case you can do the same

```
MyRunnable mr = new MyRunnable(arg1,arg2);
mr.setValue(k);

new Thread(mr).start();
```

Jason

Comment: Please check program  http://pastebin.com/wdsAxEQ6 . The value of count is 1705 if I am not use threads but if i use thread the value of the count is > 1705. Is there away where i can make int count shared by two threads? I am doing anything wrong in the program?